# Android JAVA printing in lan using localhost/printer address

Tags: java, android, printing, localhost

**Im trying to connect a lan printer to use windows spooler but i cant connect in address localhost/printer...**
I tryed to found solutions but all i find is about to use LPT1 and IP only... I need to use windows spooler to print docs and its hard to me, im trainee and dont know a lot of java language... If someone can helps i will apreciate.... 
 **When i use printer IP(192.168.15.140) the app prints normal, but when i try to use localhost/printer java returns this errors**:

> 07-12 16:19:13.921 17939-17939/com.example.dev_03.testeconnsqlsrv
>   W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView
>
> 07-12 16:19:15.066 17939-17939/com.example.dev_03.testeconnsqlsrv
>   W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "192.168.15.12/PEDIDO": No address associated with hostname

```
    public class PrinterSpooler extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public void Imprimir() {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {

            Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.15.12/PEDIDO", 9100);
            PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
            oStream.println("\n TESTANDO IMPRESSORA PELA API DO ANDROID STUDIO E VENDO A QUEBRA AUTOMATICA DE LINHA");
            oStream.println("\n\n\n");
            oStream.println("\n\n\n");
            oStream.println("\n\n\n");
            oStream.close();
            sock.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Socket("192.168.15.12/PEDIDO", 9100)` throws an exception
because `"192.168.15.12/PEDIDO"` is not a valid IP-address or host-name. Try `"192.168.15.12"` instead.

Comment: but i need to connect in windows spooler, if i use only IP, i cant reach printer in spool, only reach printer with direct connection.... If there is another way to build this code to connect printer to windows spooler it helps a lot